# EXCEL - CONDITIONAL FORMATTING (2 formula, one cell)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am struggling to have two formulas into one cell to have different conditional formatting. When I tested both formula separately, it worked. But combining it to one formula

```
=IF(I30<(TODAY()+60),"FOLLOW UP", IF(M30="COMPLETED", "DONE", ""))
```

it doesn't work as it keeps showing "Follow up" and ignored the status "Completed"

Basically what I am trying to have is "Highlight cell in PINK "TO FOLLOW UP" if it is today+60 days.. Highlight cell in GREEN "DONE" if status shows COMPLETED.

appreciate if someone could help. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: This first part `I30<(TODAY()+60),"FOLLOW UP"` within your `IF` would always be `TRUE` hence the returned value. You either need to swap around the conditions, or add an `AND` to check for column `M`. Not sure why you included `Conditional Formatting` as you would just need to add two rules.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  It didn't dawn on me that order of IF statements matter, now I know.  *-*

Answer (score 0):

Setting the cell's value and its CF are two different operations. Let's set the value first.

Most probably, the fact that a subject is "completed" is overriding any other considerations. Therefore, `IF(C5="COMPLETED","DONE"` must come first. The second condition fits into the *else* part of that IF statement. `IF((I4+60)<TODAY(),"TO FOLLOW UP","")`. There seems to be a logical error in your data calculation. Please adjust my suggestion to fit your actual needs. This would be the combined formula.

```
IF(C5="COMPLETED","DONE",IF((I4+60)<TODAY(),"TO FOLLOW UP",""))
```

Note that the date is only compared if the item isn't "completed". You might fill in the `""` of the second IF with a text that is applied if the date comparison is False.

Now you can look at the CF. It's important to remember that the cell has a color, perhaps "no color" (=white) which is shown if no conditional color is set. Then, you need a separate condition for every color you want to set, and you should specify the sequence in which the conditions are to be applied. Conditions will be applied in the sequence in which you enter them but you can also change the sequence later in the CF Manager.

Let's say, you want to follow the same logic as above: if the item is completed the cell should be green. You can use a very similar formula, `=C5="COMPLETED"`. Or you might test for the value of the cell itself, like `=B5="DONE"`. Of course, the cell value would be "DONE" if C5="COMPLETED". In either case you set the cell fill to green.

Now you can set a second format, like `=(I4+60)<TODAY()` and set the fill color to buff or pink or whatever. CF will first check the first condition and then the second and this isn't what you want. So, you go to the `Manage Rules` dialog box of the CF menu and place a checkmark in the *Stop if True* column (last on the right). This will cause Excel not to examine or apply the second condition if the first one evaluates to `True`.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  It worked the way I want it to be.  However, when I tried to copy the formula/CF to other empty rows, it shows "TO FOLLOW UP".  How should I edit the formula so I can copy to the rest of the rows for future input?  Basically when due date and status is blank, the Alert should be blank too.   I tried and it does not work.

IF(C5="COMPLETED",""","DONE",IF((A5+60)<TODAY(),"TO FOLLOW UP",IF(A5="",""))

Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: You are shifting the goal posts. (1) If C5="Completed" you want "Done". Don't change this requirement. (2) Under which you condition do you want to show "To follow up"? You never said. (3) If it's not "Done" and not "To follow up", the cell should be blank. The formula I provided meets this requirement. Therefore don't change the formula. Change the second condition, the one that shows "To follow up".

Comment: "To Follow Up" is alert for the Due date.  The original intent was to highlight items which are past due.  Was told to fix the formula to include the same highlight "To Follow Up" for a future date.  So, if I have an item which is was due on 30-Jan and status not completed, it should shows "To Follow Up" In the same context, if I have an item which will be due on 30-June-2020, it should also show "To Follow Up" 

With the new requirement, I changed part two of the formula to =IF(C2<(TODAY()+365),"TO FOLLOW UP","")